# Update records of CoreData in Swift 2

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I am trying to create a solution to update the records of CoreData, but not yet understood how this would work. To add I use the following code:

```
let newBird = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Birds", inManagedObjectContext: self.context) as! Flights
//data => NSDictionary
newBird.id = data["id"] as? String
newBird.name = data["name"] as? String
newBird.photoUrl = data["photo"] as? String\

do {
   try context.save()
}catch {
   print("erro on save")
}
```

but not yet understood how it would work to update the registry.

Can someone help me?

Comment: If you want to modify existing records, look up `NSFetchRequest` and `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Way to go guys, mark this as a duplicate question and then link to an objective C answer.